# tableView crashes after adding a object to it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue, ibaction

when a person enters something in a textField and then press the Done button, it should add that value into my NSMutableArray. Here's the code of this action:

```
- (IBAction)Fertig: (UIStoryboardSegue *)segue2;
{
KategorieTableViewNeueKategorieViewController *KategorieTVNeueKategorieVC = segue2.sourceViewController;
KategorienTableViewController *neuerKategoriename = [[KategorienTableViewController alloc]initwithData: KategorieTVNeueKategorieVC.neuerKategoriename];
[self.Kategorie addObject: neuerKategoriename];

[self.tableView reloadData];


}
```

I also do have implemented the Method initwithData but I don't know if this is right:

```
-(id)initwithData:(NSMutableString *)theName
{
if (self)
{
    self.Kategorie = [theName mutableCopy]  ;
}
return self;
}
```

I can add the value to my table view but if I scroll down to the bottom where this value should be, My App crashes and I get the error warning 'Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT'

Here is the code of my cellForRowatindexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

if (tableView == self.tableView)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = self.kategorie [indexPath.row];
}
else
{
    cell.textLabel.text = self.results [indexPath.row];
}

// Configure the cell...

    return cell;

}
```

What hace I done wrong? I'm sorry if this question is too easy but I'm new to Devlopment. If you need more Information, please ask!

Comment: I can't really understand your code. Are you creating an instance of a viewController with variable called Kategorie and then you add it to your dataSource array?
Can you also show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code?

Comment: `Kategorie` is supposed to be an `NSMutableArray`? You are initializing it as an `NSMutableString` in your `initWithData:` method. It should be `[self.Kategorie addObject:theName.mutableCopy]`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very messed up.

Your segue2 IBAction is treating your "Kategorie" property as if it is a mutable array.

(BTW, class names should start with a capital letter, and property names/iVars/method names should start with a lower-case letter. This is a very strong naming convention in iOS and Mac OS, and is actually required in order for property setter/getter methods to work correctly.)

You then posted code that is init code for SOMETHING, but you don't say what. Tell us what class that code belongs to, and post the whole header for that class.

However, your init method fails to call `[super init]`, which is an error.

Init methods should look something like this:

```
-(id)initwithData:(NSMutableString *)theName
{
  self = [super init]; //You were missing this step.
  if (self)
  {
    self.Kategorie = [theName mutableCopy]  ;
  }
  return self;
}
```

Comment: When I do this, I get the error warning Cannot assign to 'self' outside of a method in the init family